# Are there any names a Pope can’t choose?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, papal-name

Now beyond the obvious - such as the fact that you can’t select the name and monicker of a real Pope in the past, are there any specific regulations on the naming system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are there any names a Pope can’t choose?**

Although a pope is free to choose any papal of his desire, there would seem logic that any name chosen by a pope should not not be foreign to the Catholic Faith.

The basic rules for choosing a baptismal name would seem to apply here.

Canon Law states that names foreign to Christianity are not to be given to infants.

> [Can. 855](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann834-878_en.html#TITLE_I.) Parents, sponsors, and the pastor are to take care that a name foreign to Christian sensibility is not given.

**Foreign names here simply means offensive to the Catholic Church, the dignity of the child and Christianity in general.**

I guess Lucifer would be out of the question!

Pope John II (532-535) was the first pope to change his name, it was due to the fact that his given name
[**Mercury**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(mythology)) was that of a pagan Roman god and thus he was trying to avoid a scandal.

The pope Pelagius I (556-561) and Pope Pelagius II (579-590), on the other hand, both kept their given names which did not seem to either Pontiff to be a source of scandal considering the fact that the Church had just went through the Pelagian Heresy a century before! This heresy is named after its original heretic Pelagius (c.360-418).

Another way of looking at this is ask ourselves a rather simple question. For example: Should a pope change his given name if it were Apollinaris in light of the Apollinarism Heresy?

Yet the Church has both a St. Apollinaris (1st or 2nd Century) who predates Apollinarism and a St. Pelagius (912-984), who postdates Pelagianism.

There seems to be a distinction between the names of pagan gods and those of heretics. A close look at a list of Christian heresies shows us that several of the instigators of certain heresies had Christian names in one form or another. Even the names of Anti-Popes have not deterred the popes from using a particular papal name.

Comment: thanks for not just saying “Hitler” :)

Comment: @LukeHill - or "Damian"

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Catholic Answers* article [What are the criteria for a pope in choosing his new name?](https://www.catholic.com/qa/what-are-the-criteria-for-a-pope-in-choosing-his-new-name):

> **There are no official criteria**, but a pope usually chooses to honor a predecessor or someone he admires.

As for **restrictions**, there are none, but

> **it is an unwritten custom that popes do not choose the name Peter**. It is generally considered a matter of prudential judgment for popes not to invite comparisons between themselves and the pope Christ himself chose.

For more background, please see a parish article [How do Popes Choose Their Names?](https://www.stcatherinercc.org/single-post/2018/05/01/how-do-popes-choose-their-names)

- There is no canon law requiring that someone take a different name upon becoming pope, although it has become tradition since Pope John II (died 535) who chose John because his name was Mercurius (after the Roman God Mercury).
- Reasons behind the names have varied: more Italian sounding names (Pope Gregory V), honoring the Second Vatican Council (Pope John Paul I and Pope John Paul II), appealing to Saint for protection and to signify peacemaker (Pope Benedict XVI), to honor a saint (Pope Francis), etc.